# How do I get a video presented on a web page without the use of youtube -- basically bypassing their copyright suppositions

Tags: html, video, youtube

I have a video clip that I want shown on my website. I downloaded it and now it is a file in the windows media player format. Let's say it is the video clip that is the death scene from "The Interview" and I am sure youtube would remove it. So, how do I show the video on my website without using youtube? I think I remember doing this with a third party tool.

I remember something that is open source but I do not remember what it is called.  As long as you were not doing it for profit, you did not have to pay for it, as I recall.

I tried to find a solution by googling but, no matter what I tried as a search statement, the search results were always something that assumed the user was looking for some information about youtube.

Even instructions online that discuss embedding a video in XML, in truth, discuss using youtube.

Do I have to resort to Flash, "Silverlight" (if there is still such a thing) or HTML5?  Then I will have to open several cans of worms that would require making sure the user is using the right browser.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: convert the video to a format that can be used with the HTML5 video tag, probably MPEG-4/H.264 and point to the static file on the filesystem of your web server. Here is [a chart maintained by caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video) that details which browsers support which video formats for the video tag.

Avoid browser plugins such as Adobe Flash and Microsoft Silverlight. The video tag was invented to abstract away things like video player plugins and complicated object tags.

Back in *my day*, we had to offer the user a choice of watching their video in their preferred format! Anyone else remember… "Watch this in: QuickTime, Windows Media Player, RealPlayer"?

Comment: The rows are not listed in the chart you linked to at caniuse.com, so there is no way to tell which format is supported across all those browsers.  Also, the market share in the browsers does not add up to anywhere near 100%.  Do you have a more useful reference?

Answer (score 1):

IANAL but check the "fair use" provisions and the Ts&Cs of your hosting provider. YouTube has a [good overview](https://www.youtube.com/yt/copyright/fair-use.html#yt-copyright-four-factors) on this and there is a more detailed discussion [here](http://www.cmsimpact.org/fair-use/related-materials/codes/code-best-practices-fair-use-online-video).

For conversion of file formats to something you can use with the `<video>` tag in HTML5 take a look at [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) (if you need a GUI) and you should generate mp4/H.264, ogg and webm formats for widest reach. A great overview is [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html).